# Python pandas column to replace string boolean values to actual boolean type

Tags: python, pandas

I want to replace string boolean type present inside a column with actual boolean values.

```
kdf = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1' : [True, 'True', np.nan], 'dt': [datetime.now(), ' 2018-12-12', '2019-12-12'], 'bool': 
                     [False, True, True], 'bnan': [False, True, np.nan]})
```

so here, I want to convert `True`(index 1 on `col1`) to actual boolean type `True`. What I did was,

```
kdf.loc[kdf['col1'].str.contains('true', na=False, case=False)] = True
kdf.loc[kdf['col1'].str.contains('false', na=False, case=False)] = False
```

which converts the column values to actual type but I'm in need of creating a function which accepts only the df column, do an in-line replace and return the modified column (like `col.fillna`). Note that we are not allowed to pass the whole df into that func. So I can't use `df.loc`.

Also I'm bit worry about performance, is there anyother way?

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `replace`

```
df.replace({'True':True,'False':False})
# df.replace({'True':True,'False':False}).applymap(type)
Out[123]: 
              bnan            bool             col1             dt
0   <class 'bool'>  <class 'bool'>   <class 'bool'>  <class 'str'>
1   <class 'bool'>  <class 'bool'>   <class 'bool'>  <class 'str'>
2  <class 'float'>  <class 'bool'>  <class 'float'>  <class 'str'>
```

Update

```
df.replace({'True':True,'False':False},regex=True).applymap(type)
```

Sample data notice I added the leading and trailing space

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1' : [True, ' True', np.nan], 'dt': [' 2018-12-12', ' 2018-12-12', '2019-12-12'], 'bool': 
                     [False, True, True], 'bnan': ['False  ', True, np.nan]})
```

Comment: but the column having leading or trailing spaces, also I want to apply the transformation only a particular col

Answer (score 1):

```py
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x.strip().lower() == 'true')
```

I think the above should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but the column value may contain leading or trailing spaces

Comment: You could improve the condition looking for a substring or evaluating a regex in the condition. But the process of passing the column to a boolean column is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @89f3a1c's solution and @AvinashRaj's Comment:

We introduce the following data problems in the data.
1. The string `'True'` is changed to `' true  '`. This introduces case-mismatch and leading and trailing spaces.

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

kdf = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1' : [True, ' true  ', np.nan], 
                         'dt': [datetime.now(), ' 2018-12-12', '2019-12-12'], 
                         'bool': [False, True, True], 
                         'bnan': [False, True, np.nan]})

kdf['col1'] = kdf['col1'].apply(lambda x: True if str(x).strip() in ['true','True'] else False)
```

**Dataframe**:

```
    col1    dt  bool    bnan
0   True    2019-09-19 03:22:06.734861  False   False
1   true    2018-12-12 00:00:00.000000  True    True
2   NaN 2019-12-12 00:00:00.000000  True    NaN
```

**Output**:

```
    col1    dt  bool    bnan
0   True    2019-09-19 03:26:47.611914  False   False
1   True    2018-12-12 00:00:00.000000  True    True
2   False   2019-12-12 00:00:00.000000  True    NaN
```

Comment: seems like it's affecting Boolean values as well, isn't it? I mean, it does convert the actual boolean value `True` to str and then check for that val in `['true', 'True']`

Comment: I thought you wanted to have all `True` and `False` values as boolean and remove any `NAN`s. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think this would be a faster solution than checking `if x is not bool then check if the str(x) is in ['true', 'True']`.

Comment: can we just check whether the x is str or not, if yes do replace

Comment: Well you can. But I though you have a restriction of not passing the entire dataframe (and may be the entire column as well?).